# Keep NSWindow front

Tags: macos, cocoa, focus, nswindow

I open a NSWindow from my main NSWindow.

```
DropHereWindowController *dropHereWindowController = [[DropHereWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DropHereWindow"];
[dropHereWindowController showWindow:nil];
```

I want this window to stay on top of my main window when dragging a file from the finder to that "DropHereWindow". However when opening the finder (not having the focus any longer) my "DropHereWindow" goes behind my main window.

I tried orderFront, makeKey, makeKeyAndFront but nothing helped.
What can I do about it?

Answer (score 24):

Method:

```
- (void)setLevel:(NSInteger)windowLevel
```

Sub-class the NSWindow:

```
[self setLevel: NSStatusWindowLevel];
```

Or simply use:

```
[window setLevel: NSStatusWindowLevel];
```

Available levels:

- NSNormalWindowLevel
- NSFloatingWindowLevel
- NSSubmenuWindowLevel
- NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel
- NSModalPanelWindowLevel
- NSMainMenuWindowLevel
- NSStatusWindowLevel
- NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel
- NSScreenSaverWindowLevel
- kCGDesktopWindowLevel

Comment: It doesn't work, the window still goes behind my main window when clicking on the finder icon. Thanks for your answer anyway. Does anybody know how to solve that problem?

Comment: Try the different window levels one-by-one until you find the one that fits your needs, this is certainly the correct way to make your window stay on top. Are you sure the level has been been set correctly? You can check it with [self level] or [window level].

Comment: `NSFloatingWindowLevel` works for me in Mojave - my application window now stays on top of everything else! +1 - thank you.

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 4.0, Xcode 9.0**

You can set the `level` property of your `NSWindow` to `floating`. For example, if you are subclassing `NSWindow`, you can set it in the override init.

```
self.level = .floating
```

You also can get `NSWindow` from your `NSWindowController` by `self.window?`.

[There are different levels:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/window_levels)

> **NSNormalWindowLevel**
>
> The default level for NSWindow objects.
>
> **NSFloatingWindowLevel**
>
> Useful for floating palettes.
>
> **NSSubmenuWindowLevel**
>
> Reserved for submenus. Synonymous with NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel, which is preferred.
>
> **NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel**
>
> The level for a torn-off menu. Synonymous with NSSubmenuWindowLevel.
>
> **NSModalPanelWindowLevel**
>
> The level for a modal panel.
>
> **NSMainMenuWindowLevel**
>
> Reserved for the application’s main menu.
>
> **NSStatusWindowLevel**
>
> The level for a status window.
>
> **NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel**
>
> The level for a pop-up menu.
>
> **NSScreenSaverWindowLevel**
>
> The level for a screen saver.

Answer (score 11):

You say:

> I tried orderFront, makeKey, makeKeyAndFront but nothing helped.

And then:

> > Method:
> >
> > ```
> > - (void)setLevel:(NSInteger)windowLevel
> > ```
>
> It doesn't work, the window still goes behind my main window when clicking on the finder icon.

Then you're doing something wrong.

For one thing, a window shouldn't automatically go behind another window anyway. Either you're (or the user is) ordering the main window front or you're ordering the other window back. I'll assume you're not doing the latter.

For another, `orderFront:`, `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`, and `setLevel:` *do work*. In particular, `setLevel:` puts the window on an *entire other plane*, so it will *always* be in front of (or behind, depending on the level you choose) windows with the default level, no matter what you do.

I would guess that you have not hooked up, or you have accidentally disconnected, your `window` outlet to the window, which would mean you are sending your `orderFront:`/`setLevel:` messages to `nil`, which does nothing. Make sure your outlet is filled in *at the point where you send* the `orderFront:` or `setLevel:` message, by logging the window to the console. If it says “(null)” or “0x0” (depending on how you log it), then your outlet holds `nil`; check that it's hooked up in the nib and that you've already loaded the nib/instantiated the window controller.

All that said, I disagree that `setLevel:` is the correct solution. If you just want to have one window stay in front of a specific other window, and not put it on an entire other plane, [make it a child window](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/addChildWindow:ordered:).

Comment: Oops, I though he wanted the window to stay on top of everything, in which case `setLevel` is the way to go. My applications generally uses `setLevel` for drop-boxes to make them always stay on top of everything (makes dropping easier). The user can always disable this behavior with a checkbox. I agree your solution is better for ordering windows within one application.

Comment: @Anne: `setLevel:` can also be appropriate for ordering windows within a single application, in that some utility windows hide when the user switches to another application. The key question is whether you want to put the window on another plane in front of (or behind) the plane windows normally inhabit, as for tool palettes, or you just want to put a single specific window always in front of (or behind) another single specific window. I read the question as intending the latter.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me, hope that can be helpful

```
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[self.window setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSStatusWindowLevel` works, just **use it after some small delay** after starting the app (or after creating the window).

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    self.view.window.level = NSStatusWindowLevel;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `CGWindowLevelKey` `kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey` also works.

```
[window setLevel:CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey)];
```

[**CGWindowLevelKey Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGWindowLevelKey)